# Positioning Two Things Next To each other header

Tags: html, css

I need to display the text saying NAME to the left and the list to the right next to each other.

```css
body {
  font-family: nunito;
}

.mainmaneheader {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.purplebox {
  background-color: #ba68c8;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1 class="mainnameheader">NAME</h1>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">About</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

*I am aware that this is a common issue but after looking around I cannot find the answer.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Display#display_flex

Answer (score 2):

Try and give the header `display: flex;` and a `height` so you can set a `line-height` and align the text nice! After that, you can give the `ul` `width: 100%;` so it takes up the entire width as it is allowed! Then you can give the `ul` a `text-align: right` so it stays on the right!

```css
    * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    header {
        display: flex;
        height: 50px;
        line-height: 50px;
        padding: 20px;
        background-color: #fff1cc;
    }

    ul {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: right;
    }

    li {
        list-style: none;
        display: inline;
    }
```

```html
<header>
    <h1 class="mainmaneheader">NAME</h1>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1):

I did changes in "header, ul and li".

```
body {
    font-family: nunito;
}

header{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

ul {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
li{
    list-style: none;
}

.purplebox {
    background-color: #ba68c8;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, you do not actually require the css you've implemented in your `mainmaneheader` class, so I have removed it.

By assigning `inline-block` to all elements within the header, you can ensure they will appear from side by side.

```css
body {
  font-family: nunito;
}

header * {
  display: inline-block;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.purplebox {
  background-color: #ba68c8;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1 class="mainnameheader">NAME</h1>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">About</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add header display: flex to make the child elements flex and if u want to center horizontaly u can add align-items: center

```css
body {
    font-family: nunito;
}

header{
display:flex;
align-items:center;
}

.mainmaneheader {

    position: relative;
 
   
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  
}

.purplebox {
    background-color: #ba68c8;
}
```

```html
<header>
            <h1 class="mainnameheader">NAME</h1>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </header>
```